# How do I remove ._ from beginning of filename?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have several files' names starting with "._". I'd like to remove the point and underscore in a script. Howto do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Great question, but scripting q's really belong on stack overflow.

Comment: @Amanda you mean http://superuser.com/ :)

Comment: @medigeek, aah. right.

Answer (score 13):

This is a dry-run (simulates the command, doesn't execute it):

```
rename -n 's/^\._//' ._*
```

If you like the output, execute it:

```
rename -v 's/^\._//' ._*
```

Answer (score 2):

using `rename`:

```
rename -v 's/\._//' ._*
```

example:

```
$ touch ._aaa
$ rename -v 's/\._//' ._*
._aaa renamed as aaa
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be interpreted in two ways, "renaming" and "get the filename with ._ removed". For rename, see the other questions. For the second possibility, use variable expansion:

```
name=._file
stripped_name="${name#._}"
# the below will output: ._file becomes file
echo "$name becomes $stripped_name"
```